# zip file compression ratio is 0

Tags: perl, zip, compression, nfs

I have a webpage, were end-user can select and download files as zip archive(this are NFS server files). I am using Perl for the backend.

using addFile of Perl zip Archive library, the zip file is written to a socket

```
 $zip->addFile(DSNFS::check_obj_path("$Main::nfsMntDir/$origfile", $Main::nfs_server), $zipfilename);

 my $fh = *STDOUT;
if ($zip->writeToFileHandle($fh,0) != Archive::Zip::AZ_OK) {
 Log::Msg("NFS", 20, "Unable to write to file Handle");
 }
```

After downloading the zip file, the end-user is not able to extract zip files. If we check the compression ratio it is showing as zero.

Can anyone help me with this and also specify some reason why this occurs ?

Comment: A compression ratio of 0 is not unusual. Certain files do not compress well. For example, if you try to place a zip file inside of a zip file, you'll most likely won't get any further compression.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. (See [mcve].)

Comment: You are writting "binary" data to STDOUT, but you didn't use `binmode(STDOUT);`. This probably won't make a different on unixy systems, but it definitely will on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possibilities.

Firstly, you are writing to a buffered filehandle, namely STDOUT. Is that setup to autoflush? If not you may not get all of the data written to the seocket.

```
use IO::Handle; 
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

Next - when you create a zip file by writing to STDOUT, it will be created in streaming-mode. This makes the structure of the zip file slightly different from a standard zip file.

Most programs can handled streamed zip files, so it depends on what you are using to uncompress the file.

Can you post the output from the unsuccessful extraction?

Also,  post the output from running "unzip -t" against one of the downloaded files please.

Comment: tom@ubuntu:/tmp$ unzip -t file.zip
Archive:  file.zip
    testing: applications of computer.docx
  error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
At least one error was detected in file.zip.

Comment: Screenshot https://ibb.co/MDy11sH

Comment: my setup is running on autoflush

Comment: Does this help? https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/unzipping-infosphere-information-server-files-passport-advantage-result-invalid-compressed-data-inflate-error